# How to replace 'componentWillReceiveProps' to ‘getDerivedStateFromProps’?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How should I replace componentWillReceiveProps to  ‘getDerivedStateFromProps’ ?

```
  state = {
        start: null,
        end: null,
        isIncome: true,
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => this.setState({
        start: nextProps.start || null,
        end: nextProps.end || null,
        isIncome: nextProps.isIncome || false,
    })
```

Comment: FYI: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFrom` Props is called on initial render as well as on all further updates, and hence you need to store the prevProps also in state for comparison

For you use case,

```
state = {
        start: null,
        end: null,
        isIncome: true,
        prevProps: {}
}
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const { prevProps } = state;
    if(prevProps.start !== props.start || prevProps.end !== props.end || prevProps.income !== props.income){
       return {
          start: props.start || null,
          end: props.end || null,
          isIncome: props.isIncome || false,
          prevProps: props
       }
    }
    return {
       prevProps: props
    }
}
```

There are other ways to handle updates as mentioned in [**React docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> Deriving state leads to verbose code and makes your components
>   difficult to think about. Make sure you’re familiar with simpler
>   alternatives:
>
> - If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an
>     animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate
>     lifecycle instead.
> - If you want to re-compute some data only when a prop changes, use a
>     memoization helper instead.
> - If you want to “reset” some state when a prop changes, consider either
>     making a component fully controlled or fully uncontrolled with a key
>     instead.